# Do prefixes & suffixes have antonyms?

Tags: grammar, antonyms, suffixes, prefixes

## Question

Do prefixes & suffixes have antonyms? As in, is it possible for a prefix or suffix to *not* have an antonym?

## Example

Google defines "-gon" as:

> **-gon**
> *combining form*
> in nouns denoting plane figures with a specified number of angles.

I can't find any antonyms for this suffix.

I've observed that prefixes *may* have antonyms. For example, *post* being the opposite for *pre*. But is this considered to be an antonym? If so, can suffixes also have antonyms?

Comment: What would an antonym of "-gon" even mean?

Comment: The concept of an *antonym* only works with binary qualities, and even then is imperfect. As for *-gon*, it is not a morphological suffix like *-ly* or *-ness* that changes the meaning of the base word, but a *[combining form](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/how-words-are-built)* (as noted) which contributes a meaning of its own, and thus cannot be used arbitrarily. You can have a polygon, an octagon, a [164-gon](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:164-gon_rhombic_dissection2.svg), and so forth, but you can't have an *orangegon* or a *disestablishmentarianismgon* or whatnot.

Comment: How about *pro-* and *anti-*?

Comment: (Note that a lot of regular words don't have antonyms.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some prefixes and suffixes do have antonymous counterparts—sometimes *multiple*, while others don't have any (even though it would be useful if they did). "*May* have antonyms" is a good way to put it, although I hesitate to call them *antonyms* as they aren't technically *words*...

> **antonym**
>   : a word of opposite meaning *The usual antonym of good is bad.*
>   —[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antonym)

But in answer to your final question, I believe there are suffixes that *may* pair antonymously...

> **-ful** and **-less** as in *thoughtful* and *thoughtless*

You might notice that the prefixes and suffixes that *may* have antonymous counterparts are often *complementary* and not *gradable*—they have to do with binary extremes. Perhaps that's why you can't find one for **-gon**.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could argue that an 'antonym' of -gon is -hedron

> [indicating a geometric solid having a specified number of faces or
>   surfaces](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hedron)

..but it would be like saying the opposite of screw is nail. They do oppose each other in one particular facet (angle vs face, thread vs smooth), but not as a whole concept.